# Gulp Livereload in Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, livereload, gulp

The below code seems to work just fine until I go to 1ocalhost:8081...

then I get the message..

```
<pre>{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.0.5"}</pre>
```

My directory structure is....

```
____gulp
| |____build
| | |____images
| | |____index.html
| | |____scripts
| | |____styles
| |____gulpfile.js
| |____node_modules
| |____src
| | |____images
| | |____index.html
| | |____scripts
| | |____styles
```

Why isn't my html page loading? If I try to browse to 
1ocalhost:8081/build/index.html The page wont load and I get the msg

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"no such route"}
```

I've also tried the chrome plugin but I get the below msg when I hit the plugin

```
Could not connect to LiveReload server. Please make sure that LiveReload 2.3 (or later) or another compatible server is running.
```

I checked the plugin settings from the plugin in Chrome and check the option for file urls

Heres my commented code.....

```
//sudo npm install gulp -g
// install chrome extension from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei
//Go into the settings from the plugin in Chrome and check the option for file urls: chrome://extensions/


// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// include plug-ins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var lr = require('tiny-lr');
var server = lr();


// JS hint task
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(livereload(server));
});

// minify new images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  var imgSrc = './src/images/**/*',
      imgDst = './build/images';

  gulp.src(imgSrc)
    .pipe(changed(imgDst))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDst))
    .pipe(livereload(server));
});

// minify new or changed HTML pages
gulp.task('htmlpage', function() {
  var htmlSrc = './src/*.html',
      htmlDst = './build';

  gulp.src(htmlSrc)
    .pipe(changed(htmlDst))
    .pipe(minifyHTML())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(htmlDst))
    .pipe(livereload(server));
});

// JS concat, strip debugging and minify
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(['./src/scripts/lib.js','./src/scripts/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('script.js'))
    .pipe(stripDebug())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/scripts/'))
    .pipe(livereload(server));
});

// CSS concat, auto-prefix and minify
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src(['./src/styles/*.css'])
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/styles/'))
    .pipe(livereload(server));
});

// default gulp task
gulp.task('default', ['imagemin', 'htmlpage', 'scripts', 'styles'], function() {

    server.listen(8081, function (err) { if (err) return console.log(err);

          // watch for HTML changes
          gulp.watch('./src/*.html', function() {
            gulp.run('htmlpage');
          });

          // watch for JS changes
          gulp.watch('./src/scripts/*.js', function() {
            gulp.run('jshint', 'scripts');
          });

            // watch for IMG changes
          gulp.watch('./src/images/*.png', function() {
            gulp.run('imagemin');
          });

          // watch for CSS changes
          gulp.watch('./src/styles/*.css', function() {
            gulp.run('styles');
          });
    });
});
</pre>
```

And the output from gulp looks good...

```
Bills-MacBook-Pro:gulp Bill$ gulp
[gulp] Using file /Users/Bill/gulp/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to /Users/Bill/gulp
[gulp] Running 'imagemin'...
[gulp] Finished 'imagemin' in 77 ms
[gulp] Running 'htmlpage'...
[gulp] Finished 'htmlpage' in 2.47 ms
[gulp] Running 'scripts'...
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' in 4.05 ms
[gulp] Running 'styles'...
[gulp] Finished 'styles' in 1.09 ms
[gulp] Running 'default'...
[gulp] Finished 'default' in 1.38 ms
gulp.run() has been deprecated. Use task dependencies or gulp.watch task triggering instead.
[gulp] Running 'htmlpage'...
[gulp] Finished 'htmlpage' in 3.5 ms
[gulp] index.html was reloaded.
[gulp] Running 'htmlpage'...
[gulp] Finished 'htmlpage' in 712 μs
[gulp] Running 'htmlpage'...
[gulp] Finished 'htmlpage' in 1.05 ms
[gulp] index.html was reloaded.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how livereload works.  It doesn't run a server to load your content — it runs a separate server to *notify* when content changes.

When you enable livereload<sup>*</sup>, a small javascript is embedded in your page which listens to the LR server.  When you notify the server that a resource was modified, it tells any listeners, which in turn reload the resource from where ever they originally loaded the resource.

If your webapp/site/page is entirely self contained, you can simply open the `file://` url to the page you want in your browser, enable livereload, and it should work.

However, if you are dealing with external resources, you should fire up a server of some sort.  There's far too many ways for me to select one for you, but you can use connect, express, or some other node library, you could run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in your directory if you have python installed, etc.

If you want to integrate a `connect` server into your build process, I have a [recipe at the bottom of this article](http://blog.overzealous.com/post/74121048393/why-you-shouldnt-create-a-gulp-plugin-or-how-to-stop).

---

<sup>*</sup> You can enable livereload via a browser plugin or using the [`gulp-embedlr` plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-embedlr) during development, which I prefer since it works across multiple browsers and devices.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the SimpleHTTPServer in python. I personally didn't know it up to now.

Answer (score 0):

1ocalhost:8081 or localhost:8081 ? Perhaps a spelling error on the first letter.

Comment: Thanks Darryl for your kind suggestion, unfortunately it was just just a typo.